# How to extract data from a list with multiple groups?

Tags: r, list

I am new to R and I have a question about extracting data from a list with multiple groups. For example, I have a set of data like this:

```
data(iris)

iris$Group = rep(c("High","Low", each=5))
iris = iris[sample(nrow(iris)),]
mylist = list(iris[1:50,], iris[51:100,], iris[101:150,])

head(mylist)[[1]]

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species Group
51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor  High
123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica  High
147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9  virginica   Low
23           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2     setosa  High
120          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virginica   Low
141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica  High
```

Within each list, I would like to group by `Species` and calculate the P value by `t.test` of `Sepal.Length` between `Group` High and Low. For example, I would like to get the P value of between `Group` High and Low of `Species` virginica, and so on for each list.

I am confused about this. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: *"calculate the P value of Sepal.Length between Group High and Low."* The p-value based on what kind of hypothesis test? Do you mean a t-test?

Comment: Yes, I have updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you can do the following

```
lapply(mylist, function(x)
    with(x, t.test(Sepal.Length[Group == "High"], Sepal.Length[Group == "Low"])$p.value))
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.2751545
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0.5480918
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0.864256
```

Or a `purrr`/`tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(mylist, .id = "id") %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(pval = map_dbl(data, ~t.test(
        .x$Sepal.Length[.x$Group == "High"],
        .x$Sepal.Length[.x$Group == "Low"])$p.value))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  id    data               pval
#  <chr> <list>            <dbl>
#1 1     <tibble [50 × 6]> 0.275
#2 2     <tibble [50 × 6]> 0.548
#3 3     <tibble [50 × 6]> 0.864
```

---

### Update

To perform t-tests of `Sepal.Length` between `Group = "Low"` and `Group = "High"` within `Species` you can do

```
lapply(mylist, function(x)
    with(x, setNames(sapply(unique(Species), function(y)
        t.test(Sepal.Length[Group == "High" & Species == y], Sepal.Length[Group == "Low" & Species == y])$p.value), unique(Species))))
#[[1]]
#versicolor  virginica     setosa
#0.80669755 0.07765262 0.47224383
#
#[[2]]
#    setosa  virginica versicolor
# 0.6620094  0.2859713  0.2427945
#
#[[3]]
#versicolor     setosa  virginica
# 0.5326379  0.6412661  0.5477179
```

**Keep in mind that you will have to adjust raw p-values for multiple hypothesis testing.**

To account for multiple hypothesis testing, you could modify above code slightly to give

```
lapply(mylist, function(x)
    with(x, p.adjust(setNames(sapply(unique(Species), function(y)
        t.test(Sepal.Length[Group == "High" & Species == y], Sepal.Length[Group == "Low" & Species == y])$p.value), unique(Species)))))
#[[1]]
#versicolor  virginica     setosa
# 0.9444877  0.2329579  0.9444877
#
#[[2]]
#    setosa  virginica versicolor
# 0.7283836  0.7283836  0.7283836
#
#[[3]]
#versicolor     setosa  virginica
#         1          1          1
```

Here we use `p.adjust` with the default Holm correction.

Comment: I would like to have each list first group by `Species` and do a t-test between `Group` within `Species`. Does the second approach do that?

Comment: @kin182 *"do a t-test between Group within Species.*" I'm not following. A t-test compares the population means of measurements across 2 groups. Which two groups do you want to compare?

Comment: For example, t-test of `Sepal.Length` between `Group` High and Low within each of the `Species` - versicolor, virginica and setosa. There will be 3 Pvalues for each list in this case.

Comment: @kin182 Ah I see, thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Nice and neat. Thank you!